# Unexpected behaviour of JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

So, I have this Query which I am running and fetching results from db2.

If I use this Query, It returns me a list of name.

```
String query2 = "SELECT  nh.Name  FROM NameHistory nh,NameSourcing ns WHERE ns.supplierIcId = nh.nameId ";
```

But If I use this query, I get no results. (since I have some other fetches to do which are irrelavant to show here) -

```
String query2 = "SELECT nh.Name FROM NameHistory nh,NameSourcing ns ,BomItem bi,CommodityClassificationSupplierXref ccsx,MaterialMaster mm WHERE ns.supplierIcId = nh.nameId ";
```

I dont know where I am going wrong and have no idea about this. Any explanation for this ?

Comment: Well, one of the tables must be empty. This behavior is expected, and is exactly the same as with SQL. Use associations between entities, and use joins. Use left joins when necessary. You shouldn't have IDs of other entities in your entities. You should instead use associations (ManyToOne, OneToOne, etc.).

Comment: @JBNizet Hmm.. thats right actually. Should use that only. But wouldnt it be easier to use it like this instead of doing associations and joins ?

Comment: No, not at all. JPQL only allows joins if you have associations. You can only do "sort of" inner joins the way you're doing, whereas with an assocation, you can do `select city from City city where city.country.continent.name = 'Europe'`. You can't navigate through your entities without associations, which is, well, one of the biggest points of using objects.

Comment: @JBNizet Well thanks. And your advice of using left Join instead of inner Joins worked perfectly fine . Bingo !